# Ninject property binding, how to do correctly

Tags: ninject

I have installed Ninject (v4.0.30319) package in test project to test. Create test code below, unfortunately ValidateAbuse.Instance.Repository is always Null. Why Ninject do not bind repository to ValidateAbuse.Repository property? 
Some of you may suggest to use constructor binding but I can't use it due to code structure. The below code is just example and I need to find a way to bind to property.

Test method which always fail

```
 [TestMethod]
        public void PropertyInjection()
        {
          using (IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel())
          {
              kernel.Bind<ISettingsRepository>().To<SettingsRepository>();
              Assert.IsNotNull(ValidateAbuse.Instance.Repository);
          }
        }
```

The repository interface

```
public interface ISettingsRepository
{
    List<string> GetIpAbuseList();
    List<string> GetSourceAbuseList();  
}
```

The repository implementation

```
 public class SettingsRepository : ISettingsRepository
    {
        public List<string> GetIpAbuseList()
        {
            return DataAccess.Instance.Abuses.Where(p => p.TypeId == 1).Select(p => p.Source).ToList();
        }

        public List<string> GetSourceAbuseList()
        {
            return DataAccess.Instance.Abuses.Where(p => p.TypeId == 2).Select(p => p.Source).ToList();
        }
    }
```

The class to which I am trying to bind repository

```
public class ValidateAbuse 
    {        
        [Inject]
        public ISettingsRepository Repository { get; set; }

        public static ValidateAbuse Instance = new ValidateAbuse();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Ninject will only bind properties on an object when it creates an instance of that object. Since you are creating the instance of ValidateAbuse rather than Ninject creating it, it won't know anything about it and therefore be unable to set the property values upon creation.

EDIT:

You should remove the static singleton from ValidateAbuse and allow Ninject to manage it as a singleton.

```
kernel.Bind<ValidateAbuse>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
```

Then when you ask Ninject to create any class that needs an instance of ValidateAbuse, it will always get the same instance.

It seems like you don't fully understand how Ninject works or how to implement it so I would suggest you read the wiki https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/How-Injection-Works and follow some more basic examples before trying to wire it into an existing application.

Comment: Then how to create ValidateAbuse class and use injected repository?

Comment: I already read this and it do not help in my current situation. You just wrote how to create one instance of class and bind it. But how to get instance? I have abstract class ConverterBase, I need to access  singleton ValidateAbuse instance from that class. I can't use ConverterBase Contructor to inject ValidateAbuse class. If I add property with Inject attribute, Ninject do nothing.

Comment: As I said, it's because you are not resolving instances via Ninject. You need to use Ninject to create the instance you need the dependencies resolved for. Read this page too https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/The-Activation-Process

Comment: The article explain how to use kernel.Get to activate class and initialize in such way in which it is binded. Everything is clear and I could use kernel.Get<ValidateAbuse> to get class where it is needed. But somewhere I have read that usage of kernel.Get is not good practice.

Comment: @Tomas The thing that's bad practice is sprinking Gets around your application wildly - which is Service Location. There has to be a Get somewhere, and in general, there should be one, and it should be in a Composition Root. Can I suggest you run to http://manning.com/seemann and save yourself trying to understand all this stuff SO question by SO question? I've read the book and would have saved myself months getting to understanding all this the hard way had it existed then. And while you're reading the book, go read Mark Seemann's top-voted answers here - you'll get a lot from that too