# kernel.Get to get singleton instance

Tags: ninject

I have `ConverterTest` class where I need to access `ValidateTest` class. I can't pass `ValidateTest` using constructor because `ConverterTest` is abstract class. If I introduce second constructor to bind `ValidateTest` I will get numerous problems in derived classes and many things will need to change. So I have tried to pass `ValidateTest` to `ConverterTest` using property injection(decorated with inject attribute) but that also do not work because `ConverterTest` is not created by Ninject and inject properties are ignored. So I decided to create Instance property directly in `ValidateTest` class and bind instance of itself. To get instance of `ValidateTest` in `ConverterTest` class I use `kernel.Get<ValidateTest>().Instance`. Everything works fine but is it good idea to use `kernel.Get` to access instance class? Is there any other solution?

```
public class ValidateTest
{

        private readonly ISettingsRepository _settingsRepository;

        [Inject]
        public ValidateTest Instance { get; set; }

        public ValidateTest(ISettingsRepository settingsRepository)
        {
            _settingsRepository = settingsRepository;            
        }
}
```

Binding

```
kernel.Bind<ISettingsRepository>().To<SettingsRepository>();
kernel.Bind<ValidateAbuse>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
```

Getting instance of `ValidateTest` using `kernel.Get` in abstract class where constructor binding is not possible and property binding is not working.

```
public abstract class ConverterTest
{

        public void Execute()
        {
          NinjectHelper.kernel.Get<ValidateTest>().Instance
        }
}
```

Comment: Isn't the whole point of a DI container to hold the instance for you, so you don't have to ever worry about whether your objects are singletons or not?

Comment: @cHao There are cases where you only want your object created once for all users (often in a website). The point of a DI container is to allow you to create the instance from an outside location.

Comment: Is that Instance supposed to be static? Why does ValidateTest appear to have a circular reference to another one? Have to say I can't make hear or tail of your question. The first paragraph is impenetrable for me. Can you perhaps re-ask a simpler question? Def +1 on @cHao - Ninject can manage instancing of something in the container but the natural way to do all this is to have no singletons, static things or magic Instance methods. If someone needs an X, they either request it via ctor injection (or Propery Setter Injection), or outside of proper DI, you can do a Kernel.Get

Comment: (But a Kernel.Get, when outside of a composition root is normally Service Location - in fact having more than one Get is not a good smell either way)

Comment: I rescind my advice to re-ask unless you're actually going to close dups. You are def thinking about it wrong wanting to have magic Instance accessors that you seem to want to use for undescribed purposes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ninject property binding, how to do correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10188451/ninject-property-binding-how-to-do-correctly)

Answer (score 1):

Why not have your subclasses of `ConverterTest` set the ValidateTest either via an exposed property in ConverterTest or constructor's of their own?

```
public abstract class ConverterTest
{
     protected ValidateTest ValidateTest{get;set;}

     public void Execute()
     {
         ValidateTest.ValidateStuff();
     }
}

public class ConcreteConverter : ConverterTest
{
    [Inject]
    public ConcreteConverter(ValidateTest validateTest)
    {
        base.ValidateTest = validateTest;
    }
}
```

Or, I think that you could make the property public `public ValidateTest ValidateTest{get;set;}`  and it should work for property injection if you add the appropriate attribute.

```
public abstract class ConverterTest
{
     [Inject]
     public ValidateTest ValidateTest{get;set;}

     public void Execute()
     {
         ValidateTest.ValidateStuff();
     }
}
```

Comment: The second example will not work because Ninject cannot inject into properties that do not have public setter.

Comment: @Tomas I think there's a private reflection in the NinjectSettings, but no, OOTB private reflection isnt std